# Can't iterate over my API generated array using the forEach() method

Tags: javascript, foreach, fetch-api

After troubleshooting with console.log/debugger it seems like I cannot iterate over my API generated array at the forEach method call in the function addListItem.

However I can see the pokemonNameList array being populated in the forEach iteration in the loadList function.

What am I doing wrong?

```
const apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=15';
const pokemonNameList = [];

function getAll() {
    return pokemonNameList;
  }

function add(pokemon) {
    if (typeof pokemon === 'object') {
      pokemonNameList.push(pokemon);
    }
  }

function loadList() {
    return fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        data.results.forEach((item) => {
          fetch(item.url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((inneritem) => {
              const pokemon = {
                name: inneritem.name,
                height: inneritem.height,
                weight: inneritem.weight
              };
              add(pokemon);
              console.log(pokemonNameList);// I can see the array here
            });
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        console.log(pokemonNameList);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  }

function addListItem(pokemon) {
    console.log('I cannot see this console log');//This does not show up
    const card = document.createElement('li');
    const cardbody = document.createElement('div');
    const name = document.createElement('h1');

    card.classList.add('card');
    cardbody.classList.add('card-body');
    name.classList.add('card-title');
    name.innerText = pokemon.name;

    cardbody.appendChild(name);
    card.appendChild(cardbody);
    pokemonList.appendChild(card);
  }

loadList()
  .then(() => {
    getAll().forEach((item) => {
      console.log('Hello from inside the forEach');//I cannot see this
      addListItem(item);
    });
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.error(e);
  });
```

Comment: what does `pokemonRepo.getAll()` return?

Comment: Share a sample data so we can see what you are dealing with.

Comment: Updated the code with the getALL function! Not sure how else to share the code, as this is the code. It's suppose to use the API data to populate the card created in the addlistitem function and display it in a browser

Comment: If `forEach` isn't working then it's not an array. Try calling `Array.isArray(generatedArray)`

Comment: I don't see pokemonRepo being declared; am I missing something?

Comment: I apologize the pokemonrepo is because I have this in an IIFE so it was to gain access to it. I removed the pokemonrepo for clarification

Comment: @I0_ol the call returns true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not waiting for the inner `fetch(item.url)`s so when you call getAll no item has been pushed yet.

you can do that by changing forEach to map, returning the promise and adding a promise.all... something like this:

```
function loadList() {
    return fetch(apiUrl)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        return Promise.all(data.results.map((item) => {
          return fetch(item.url)
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I created all the functions up to the place where you mentioned the error

```js
const pokemonNameList = []; // Pokemon Array
const apiUrl = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=15'; // API URL
// To prevent duplicates, in case of calling the loadList function multiple times, i'm passing the index from the response, to replace the element at the same index
const add = (pokemon, index) => pokemonNameList[index] = (pokemon);
const getAll = _ => pokemonNameList; // Short arrow function to return pokemonNameList

async function loadList() {
    const response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=5');
    const result_1 = await response.json();

    Promise.all(result_1.results.map((item, index) => fetch(item.url).then(response_1 => response_1.json()).then(({
        name,
        height,
        weight
    }) => add({
        name,
        height,
        weight
    }, index)))).then(() => getAll().forEach(pokemon => console.log(pokemon)));
}
```

Comment: It would help if you were to explain what exactly you have changed

Comment: Oh sorry, I did with the comments. But I'll write it outside the function too

Comment: I tried using the .map method instead and using a return but it's not working

Comment: Did you return the `fetch` in the `map`

Comment: I tried it both in .map brackets and after the add(pokemon) function call

Comment: Nothing prints out on the screen. There are no errors in the console. PokemonNameList shows up as true for array and it contains the data requested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229842/discussion-between-a-mola-and-andreas-c).